# Uploading and writting files to Ubuntu EC2 Instance

Tags: php, file-upload

I am new to AWS and now I have an issue. I am developing a mobile app that uses PHP files as web services to query a MySQL database.
PHP files and MySQL are hosted on a AWS EC2 instance.
I have no problem accessing the PHP files from my mobile app.
The issue I have now is that I need to upload a file from the app to the server.

Here you have the PHP file that is used to receive and save the file to the server:

```
<?php
  $image = $_POST['image'];
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $realImage = base64_decode($image);
  
  file_put_contents($name,$realImage);
  echo "OK";
?>
```

In the app I am receiving the response `"OK"` , but the file is not saved to the server folder. I guess this is a matter of permissions.
I can access the server through FTP. I gave the permissions to the ubuntu instance user as follows:

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /var/www/html
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html
```

But I don´t know what should I do to let me upload files from the app to the server without issues.

Comment: Your code doesn't care if `file_put_contents()` succeeds or not, it will say 'OK' in all cases other than a fatal error. You need to check what the return value is.

Comment: @Sammitch; you are right, but I have included the lines ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); and after that the response is: <b>Warning</b>:  file_put_contents(image_picker_D3C63D1B-8283-471E-87FF-08076214E67B-52105-0000164BF499DE5D.jpg): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in <b>/var/www/html/almacen/avatars/subir_foto_perfil.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />
OK

Comment: Then you have a permission issue on the folder you're trying to write the file to. You're probably not running your web server as the "ubuntu" user. Check your web server config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, and very important, the question doesn't have anything to do with AWS. You have Ubuntu server that runs web server and PHP and you can't upload a file in your application.

Second, you are tinkering with permissions in `/var/www/html`. That is not where the file is uploaded. The location is controlled by `upload_tmp_dir` in your `php.ini`. By default the location is system temp directory. Uploading user files into web root is a very bad security practice. What prevents a mailicious user to upload some script, and then access it from the browser and execute it?!

Finally, if your `upload_tmp_dir` is pointing to some non-default location, it needs to be writeable by web server. Is your web server running as `ubuntu`? It's usually `apache` or `nginx`, depending what web server you are running

Take a look at [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) that combines client and server-side code

Comment: Yes, it is Ubuntu instance. What I need in this case is to upload the app user profile image to the server. I need to save the image to a folder that can be accessed from the app. What is your advice?

Comment: wait - I may have confused two questions. There are two parts - first your browser uploads the file into `/tmp`, and then your PHP copies the file to the destination of your choice. I updated the answer with a link to example code

Comment: Felix, the app is uploading the file to the server, the PHP file is hosted on var/www/html/almaacen/avatars

Comment: i am using that kind of file in multiple projects. The issue in this case is a matter of permsissions to the folder

Comment: here you have the complete response: <b>Warning</b>:  file_put_contents(image_picker_D3C63D1B-8283-471E-87FF-08076214E67B-52105-0000164BF499DE5D.jpg): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in <b>/var/www/html/almacen/avatars/subir_foto_perfil.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />

Comment: while I would still prefer `move_uploaded_file()`, but if you are using `file_put_contents()` - what if you put full path explicitly (maybe even hard code for testing). Then, if you still have permission denied - chmod the directory in error to 777 and see what is the owner on the file. That's how I would troubleshoot

Comment: I have created a new user group callled avatars that includes users ubuntu and www-data, now It works fine, no issues saving the file, do you think it is a good practice?